# Rails Test::Unit does not work. But app works, console works, even console in Test::Unit works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

I have a method that simply updates an attribute. :

```
@objects.each do |thingamabobber|
  thingamabobber.update_attributes( { attribute_one: false, attribute_two: true } )
end
```

It does a little bit more, but for the most part, that's it. I place a debugger before that update part and after it. And I notice while running a Unit::Test, it doesn't update the attribute.

But if in that same debugger, just copy and paste the code in the Test::Unit console, it will update with no errors. That goes for if I use Rails console, or if I use the app as a whole. Everything works fine. Except for the test.

Note, nothing is getting stubbed in my test objects. I'm using Factory girl to create my objects.

Further, if I were to throw the debugger in the tests, and run a collection on the attributes that I'm updating, they will return back *unchanged*, **but still pass the tests**, that is, except for one test that makes sure that attribute_one is updated.

This tell me that..Test::Unit is silently processing the data, and that its failing, but not for any of the reasons its telling me.

Does anyone know what this may be symptomatic of?

**Update**

Here's it really simplified :

```
should "update all items" do
  @item.items.last.update_all_recurring_items( {"name" => 'Ooooohhhh Yeeeeeea! Kooolaid Goooooood!'} )
  assert_equal @item.name, @item.items.last.name
end
```

Then the method in my model :

```
def update_all_recurring_items params = {}
  parent = self.recurring_items.present? ? self : Item.find(self.recurring_item_id)
  parent.recurring_items.each do |item|
    # Everything ok up to here. If I run the below method it works.
    item.update_attributes( params )
    # But! The Test Suit just skips over this like nothing ever happened.
  end
  parent.update_attributes(params) if self != parent
end
```

Comment: Do you have any validations? `update_attributes` checks the validations, check `@item.items.last.errors` maybe?

Comment: Hmmm.. nope no errors. And it passes all validations, because it works within the App, within the console, within the console for Test::Unit, but not within the test.

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe in your test you create your objects somewhat differently, which could cause the validations to fail. Can you see in the `test.log` that the correct `INSERT/UPDATE` statement is executed?

Comment: Thanks Nathanvda for your comment. On closer inspection of the logs I've noted a `rollback` that comes after a `release savepoint`. I'll show that pertinent part above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the answer was to *reload* the object so that the test instantiated the object.

So simply doing this :

```
@object.reload
```

Allowed all the tests to pass, and the console to reflect the changes in the Test::Unit.

Though, I'm curious why that is.

Comment: Ha! If you do `@item.items.last.update_recurring_items` you will fetch all items from the parent, but since rails is currently not using an identity map, this change is stored in the database, but not in `@item.items.last`, so indeed: you have to do `@item.items.last.reload` to sync with the database. Is that clear? In web-use that is not a problem most of the time, because on the next request all data is automatically reloaded. HTH.

Comment: Ah I thought that was why, but now you illustrated specifically what was happening. I appreciate that. Thanks.